# How to fill Dictionary dynamically

Tags: swift, dictionary

I parse CSV file loaded into content: String variable. File has three values on each of its rows and I'd like to fill Dictionary using three keys (autID, autSName, autFName). I wrote code below

```
var valuesDict = Dictionary<String,Any>()
let dataRows = content.components(separatedBy: "\n")

for dataRow in dataRows {
    let values = dataRow.components(separatedBy: ";")
    if Int64(values[0]) != nil {
        valuesDict.updateValue(Int64(values[0])!, forKey: "autID")
        valuesDict.updateValue(values[1], forKey: "autSName")
        valuesDict.updateValue(values[2], forKey: "autFName")
    }
}
```

Parsing is working fine but dictionary contents values only from the last data line even if updateValue method is documented as "Updates the value stored in the dictionary for the given key, or adds a new key-value pair if the key does not exist." so I assumed that it will add all unique key-value combinations into valuesDict dictionary. What I'm doing wrongly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is an **array** format, a line for the field names and subsequent lines representing the records.

You have to declare an array

```
var valuesArray = [Dictionary<String,Any>]()
let dataRows = content.components(separatedBy: "\n")

for dataRow in dataRows {
    let values = dataRow.components(separatedBy: ";")
    if let autID = Int64(values[0]) {
        valuesArray.append(["autID": autID, "autSName": values[1], "autFName": values[2])
    }
}
```

further you might drop the first line. And this is Swift, a custom struct is preferable over a *primitive* dictionary.